# Proxy property in setter has never type (with MRE)

Tags: typescript

With TypeScript 4.5.4 (current latest), this code (see below or [in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeBYAKBhjAFc4AuGAWgEYAaQ4gQwCdWqBtBmAJnpgBmALqMiMaBxgByaWIC+AbkKFQkWAAdWIAB4IsJAKYB3GAAVtegBSJUaAfnERDUK1DYBzFwK0gNVAGtDBBAAMxgoBA1DMPhkdAEAN2YAG1JDAEpcJmIYAHoAKhJwQxhYqAALQ2cYYxBWAIgYAryc4jy8mAA1Q1YAOhhaNpgAS3CrXw1RsAjPFyz3Vi8oTknhA2S0w2Vxds6e-r5hxeXV7Q117E30ndz8-d6BwWO5lcmYZiagkPDI6NjbOhLjBrtthh1uo8YAAWYYQYwjKDACowCbnLKOO7EYCfUrSMhwaQUYbY3EySREkm5E4uM5+YGg25Y4goViGZgBJnEeQqXb5IrGCojFKlSrVUp1BpNFrgh6HACscIRSJRaL8GKpOJq+PIlL5dxpb3ODNSNypLLZHK5uS1eIpxP11NedIuG1NYMdFvZnOGPL5EIOAwAbErEcjUZMNY7bTICXrmcRDS6TVtrXdWd60zAACaGULMUgpKAOhOzJa0tZu1PmmAZq2+3l3NlQUisGZQVhm8TyBQZHaqcAQEAivopEAeKzSXx6GBUOQwacIPuEIA)) is throwing error `Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)` for the version 1,2,3,4 yet for version 5 and 6 no error is reported. If we remove one of the `num` prop or `str`, all the errors are gone.

Is there an explanation for this design?

```js
const myObj = {
  num: -1,
  arr: [1, 2, 3],
  str: '',
};

const proxy = new Proxy(myObj, {
  set(target, prop: keyof typeof myObj, value) {
    /* none of these works */
    // Ver. 1
    if (prop in target) target[prop] = value;
    // Ver. 2
    target[prop] = value;
    // Ver. 3
    target[prop as keyof typeof myObj] = value;
    // Ver. 4
    switch (prop) {
      case 'num':
      case 'str':
        target[prop] = value;
        break;
    }

    /* while these works */
    // Ver. 5
    switch (prop) {
      case 'num':
        target[prop] = value;
        break;
      case 'str':
        target[prop] = value;
        break;
    }
    // Ver. 6
    switch (prop) {
      case 'num':
        target[prop] = value;
        break;
      default:
        target[prop] = value;
        break;
    }

    return true;
  },
});

console.log('proxy : ', proxy);
```

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe. I think if stack overflow encourages people to offer problems with MRE, I should be allowed to write it in the title. I hate those questions without it. Could you explain why you want to remove it?

Comment: For the same reason you don't say "post contains question" or "I've written it in English" in the title - they're basic requirements, per [ask]. Questions _without_ an MRE, which I agree are a problem, are _closed_ and/or *downvoted*; we don't edit "(without MRE)" into the title.

Comment: I like your way to explain it, it funny and clear! I saw a lot of questions with huge code chunks and I don't want to answer them for not having MRE(nor are they closed), so I assumed MRE was not a must, sorry for the confusion. I hope we can close as many non-MRE problem as we can. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you filed [ms/TS#47295](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47295) which is marked "working as intended" with the answer about ms/TS#30769.  So do you want to close this question?  Or are you still interested in an answer here?  And are you interested in the "right" way to do it (which would involve generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOzDzW)), or just an explanation?

Comment: I still don't understand whether you want to close this question here, or whether you want someone to post an answer here which may end up similar to what's already said in ms/TS#47295.

Comment: @jcalz Yes I do want to close it but I don't know how to. Should I answer it myself and close it?

Comment: I rolled back to (with MRE) version because I see a lot of questions without MRE again and not being taken care of. I suggest we all add a (MRE) in the title so everyone will see its importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summarized

Writing produces type intersection in TS.

### Detailed

This is a copy of the answer from the official repo [microsoft/TypeScript#47295](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47295), this is a functionality that "work as intended".

> In most of your setups, the type of `prop` is not narrowed down from `"num" | "str" | "arr"`; since you're *writing* to `target[prop]` rather than reading from it, that produces an intersection (not a union) of all the possible types it could refer to. If there's no overlap, the intersection collapses to `never`, because there's no possible value that works for all of them.

This answer is created to close the question.